# Binding to a property of a property

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I have an object structure:

```
MainObject
   Object1
     Property1
   Object2 
     Property1
```

I need to bind a control to Property1 of Object1.

Should it be

```
myBinding.Source = MainObject;
myBinding.Path = new PropertyPath("Object1.Property1");
txt.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, binding);
```

or

```
myBinding.Source = MainObject.Object1;
myBinding.Path = new PropertyPath("Property1");
txt.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, binding);
```

If the answer is the second option, is there a way to pass the name of an object as a parameter other than creating a dictionary? SomeFunction(string objectname). I know you cannot do it directly but since Object1 is a property of a MainObject, can I get to it by passing a string "Object1" to some function?

Comment: Did you try any or both of your own suggestions? Both should work as far as the binding path is concerned.

Comment: where do you want to pass "Object1"?

Answer (score -1):

I was able to do what I needed with the first option. The second one works if I type the object name directly but I couldn't find a way to pass the object name as a string as I can in the first option. I guess it could be done through reflection but I am not sure of the proper way.